# como requerir campos en graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql

Estoy intentando requerir campos en graphql, entiendo que cuando un campo en graphql se requiere el schema se hace de la siguiente manera

```
`query { ping!: String }`
```

pero en esta ocacion estoy utilizando `GraphQLSchema` para crear los schemas, tengo lo sigueinte

```
export const Authschema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "QueryTypeAuthentication",
    fields: {
      signin: {
        type: ResponseAuthentication,
        description: "query for authentication of user.",
        args: { signin: { type: InputSignin, description: "Arguments to login." }},
        resolve: (root, { signin }, { user}) => {
          return {
            error: false,
            success: true,
            message: "",
          };
        },
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

como deberia hacer para que los argumentos de `InputSignin` sean requeridos? saludos.

Answer (score -1):

En el tipo, puedes especificar la [clase `GraphQLNonNull`](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlnonnull) para forzar que los valores no sean nulos. Algo como esto:

```
type: new GraphQLNonNull(InputSignin)
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).